# Why doesn't pkg-config support CXXFLAGS?

Tags: pkg-config

I noticed that pkg-config only offers `CFLAGS` and `LIBS` (aka `LDFLAGS`).

Why aren't there any support for pkg-config to offer `CXXFLAGS`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yea, question was over a year ago

IMHO - this should be fixed but that will take a long time.  Meanwhile you will come across conflicting flags. The best example of conflicting flags I can think of is the "--std=???" option - which when used wrong, causes warnings.

Step 1- Put both "--std=c99" and "--std=c++11" in the PC file.
Step 2- Require uses to do the following in their Makefile

```
PKG_CFLAGS := $(shell pkg-config --cflags FILENAME.pc)
CFLAGS     := $(filter-out --std=c99, ${PKG_CFLAGS})
CXXFLAGS   := $(filter-out  --std-c++11,${PKG_CFLAGS})
```

Problem: This does not play well with autoconfig, and Cmake based stuff :-(

Comment: I don't like the idea that a pkg-config needs such hard work by the user. A much easier workaround is to ask the user to use a specific standard and don't write it in the pkg-config. However, the best solution would be that Cxxflags existed in pkg-config, of course.  Also, I would argue against writing `-std=c99` in a .pc file, because another library may request `-std=gnu17`, and then you have a problem.  It's better to ask for a set of standards in the documentation, and let the user choose the right one.